# PHPMailer - PHP Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mail' not found in /.............../crons/Mail.php on line 2
```

Any idea why it says 'Mail' when it's not mentioned in the code?
Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php
    require("database.php");
    include_once("Mail.php");
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `sent`='0' LIMIT 50");
    if ($query->rowCount()>=1)
    {
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        $email = stripslashes($row['message']);
        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
        $mail->Port = 25;
        //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
        $mail->Username = "help@pingrglobe.com";
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = "ping123rglobe";
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom('help@pingrglobe.com', 'PingrGlobe Support');
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        $mail->addReplyTo('help@pingrglobe.com', 'PingrGlobe Support');
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress($row['email'], 'John Doe');
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = $row['subject'];
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->Body = $email;

        //send down here etc
```

So basically, I got this code and I get the error as stated above the code, and it's not doing anything. Brand new PHPMailer download, "Mail" is not even a class being used, I'm confused.

You might need the first few lines of Mail.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer - PHP email creation and transport class.
 * PHP Version 5.0.0
 * Version 5.2.7
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/
 * @author Marcus Bointon (coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2013 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, PHPMailer will only run on PHP version 5 or greater!\n");
}

/**
 * PHPMailer - PHP email creation and transport class.
 * PHP Version 5.0.0
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @author Marcus Bointon (coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2013 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 */
class PHPMailer
{
    /**
     * The PHPMailer Version number.
     * @type string
     */
    public $Version = '5.2.7';
```

Comment: what's in Mail.php on line 2? I am guessing there's a reference to a class "Mail" that doesn't exist? Could you tell us what's in the first few lines of Mail.php?

Comment: @NaveedHasan added to OP.

Comment: lol at `/.............../crons/Mail.php`

Comment: I didn't want the full path showing lol, it's like a billion chars long.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your `php.ini's` include_path points to the `PEAR` directory. If you installed PEAR through the console and had `PEAR` automatically add its path to `php.ini`, remember that the added include_path will be available after you have restarted your web server.

It's also important to check the correct case

```
include_once("mail.php") //without a capital M.
```

Comment: File name is capital.

Comment: Where do I find the pear directory on CentOS and where in the PHP.ini should I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that , create correct $mail object for PHPmailer.

$mail = (object) new PHPmailer();

Try this sample:

```
<?php

include_once('class.PHPmailer.php');


       $mailer = (object) new PHPmailer();                  

$your_Email ='abc@gmail.com';
//$mailer->AddBCC("");
$mailer->From = "no.reply@gmail.com";    
$mailer->FromName = "no.reply@gmail.com";  
$mailer->AddAddress($your_Email);

$mailer->Subject = "Thanks for contacting ...";

$mailer->Body= "";
$mailer->Body.="<br>";

$mailer->Body.= "  Thanks for contacting us .";
$mailer->Body.="<br>";

$mailer->Body.="<br><br><table>
               <tr><td align='left' >&nbsp;</td></tr>   
<tr><td align='left' style='color:#828282;font-size:10px;' >Note: For your privacy and protection, please do not forward this mail to anyone as it allows you to get 
automatically logged into your account. This is an automated email and please do not reply to this mail.</td></tr>

</table>";
//echo $mailer->Body;
                       //send mail as HTML
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
//set charset
$mailer->CharSet = "utf-8";
//set mailing method... mail, smtp or sendmail
$mailer->Mailer = "sendmail";
$mailer->Send();
/*if ($mailer->Send())
{ 

  echo"TRUE SENT MAIL";
}
else
{

echo "FAIL";

}*/
}
/*     SEND MAIL         */
?>
```